# Spring Integration - channels and threads

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I would like to understand how messages are processed in Spring Integration: serial or parallel. In particular I have an inbound channel adapter with a poller and an HTTP outbound gateway. I guess splitters, transformers, header enrichers etc are not spawning their own threads.

I could have missed them, but are these details specified somewhere in the documentation?

Also can I programatically get all the channels in the system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Channel types are [described here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/channel.html).

The default channel type is `Direct` (the endpoint runs on the caller's thread); `QueueChannel` and `ExcecutorChannel` provide for asynch operations.

`context.getBeansOfType(MessageChannel.class)`

Comment: Broken link - this one is working for me, these days https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/channel.html ("Message Channels" section in the Spring docs)

Answer (score 4):

Actually "threading" dependes on `MessageChannel` type:

E.g. `DirectChannel` (`<channel id="foo"/>` - default config) doesn't do anything with threads and just shifts the message from `send` to the subscriber to handle it. If the handler is an `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler` it sends its result to the `outputChannel` and if the last one is `DirectChannel`, too, the work is done within the same Thread.

Another sample is about your `inbound channel adapter`. On the background there is a scheduled task, which executes within the Scheduler thread and if your poll is very often the next poll task might be executed within the new Thread.

The last "rule" is acceptable for `QueueChannel`: their `handle` work is done with Scheduler thread, too.

`ExcecutorChannel` just places the `handle` task to the `Executor`.

All other info you you can find in the Reference Manual provided by Gary Russell in his answer.